# Proper way to customize Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend and Drupal.ajax.prototype.success functions

Tags: ajax

Is there any proper way to customize **Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend** and **Drupal.ajax.prototype.success** functions? I just wanted to add additional effect to the inserting and removing of Throbber container, but I couldn't find any way to achieve this. Then I created a new js file and copied the whole functions and modified them. After that I added the file with drupal_add_js() with additional check, like this:

```
if (!path_is_admin(current_path())) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'carroza') . '/js/custom.js', array('type' => 'file', 'group' => JS_THEME));
  }
```

This is working fine, but I think this kind of approach is wrong and is not convenient.

Comment: Your approach is called ["Monkey patching"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)...it's the only way to override an existing object's methods in Javascript. It might be inconvenient, but that's what the language provides I'm afraid.